# How to iterate an expression?

Tags: python, scrapy

This is in relation to web scraping, specifically scrapy. I want to be able to iterate an expression to create my items. As an example, lets say I import the item class as "item." In order to then store an item, I would have to code something like:

```
item['item_name'] = response.xpath('xpath')
```

My response is actually a function so it actually looks something like:

```
item['item_name'] = eval(xpath_function(n))
```

This works perfectly. However, how can I iterate this to create multiple items with different names without having to manually name each one? The code below does not work at all (and I didn't expect it to), but should give you an idea of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
for n in range(1, 10):
    f"item['item_name{n}'] = eval(xpath_function(n))"
```

Basically trying to create 10 different items names `item_name1` - `item_name10`. Hope that makes sense and I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just creating keys for your dictionary based on the value of `n` you could try something like:

```
for n in range(10): 
    item['item_name' + str(n+1)] = eval(xpath_function(n+1))
```

If you need to format the number (e.g. include leading zeros), you could use an f-string rather than concatenating the strings as I did.

[NB your for loop as written will only run from 1 to 9, so I have changed this in my answer.]